# scala sbt libraryDependencies provided - Avoid downloading 3rd party library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I've the following Spark Scala code that references 3rd party libraries,

```
package com.protegrity.spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2
import com.protegrity.spark.udf.ptyProtectStr
import com.protegrity.spark.udf.ptyProtectInt

class ptyProtectStr extends UDF2[String, String, String] {
  
  def call(input: String, dataElement: String): String = {
    return ptyProtectStr(input, dataElement);
  }
}

class ptyUnprotectStr extends UDF2[String, String, String] {
  
  def call(input: String, dataElement: String): String = {
    return ptyUnprotectStr(input, dataElement);
  }
}

class ptyProtectInt extends UDF2[Integer, String, Integer] {
  
  def call(input: Integer, dataElement: String): Integer = {
    return ptyProtectInt(input, dataElement);
  }
}

class ptyUnprotectInt extends UDF2[Integer, String, Integer] {
       
       def call(input: Integer, dataElement: String): Integer = {
                     return ptyUnprotectInt(input, dataElement);
       }
}
```

I want to create JAR file using SBT. My build.sbt looks like the following,

```
name := "Protegrity UDF"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.protegrity.spark" % "udf" % "2.3.2" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2" % "provided"
)
```

As you see, I trying to create a thin JAR file using "provided" option as my Spark environment already contains those libraries.

In spite of using "provided", sbt is trying to download from maven and throwing below error,

```
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.protegrity.spark:udf:2.3.2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\com.protegrity.spark\udf\2.3.2\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/protegrity/spark/udf/2.3.2/udf-2.3.2.pom
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:249)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$35(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:218)
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:218)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2950)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.protegrity.spark:udf:2.3.2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\com.protegrity.spark\udf\2.3.2\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/protegrity/spark/udf/2.3.2/udf-2.3.2.pom
```

What change in build.sbt should I make to skip the maven download for "com.protegrity.spark"?  Interestingly, I don't face this issue for "org.apache.spark" on the same build

Comment: Provided just mean that an uber jar won't include those libraries, but you still need them to compile. How, do you expect the compiler to check your code?

Comment: Check this out if you have old intelij add this option https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlbTV.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the JAR file available (but not through Maven or another artifact repository) wherever you're compiling the code, just place the JAR in (by default) the `lib` directory within your project (the path can be changed with the `unmanagedBase` setting in `build.sbt` if you need to do that for some reason).

Note that this will result in the unmanaged JAR being included in an assembly JAR.  If you want to build a "slightly less fat" JAR that excludes the unmanaged JAR, you'll have to filter it out.  One way to accomplish this is with

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp.filter(_.data.getName == "name-of-unmanaged.jar")
}
```

If you don't have the JAR (or perhaps something very close to the JAR) handy, how exactly do you expect the compiler to typecheck your calls into the JAR?